# Array bash script doesn't work

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
ARRAYNAME=( 'time1' 'life' 'time2' )
echo ${ARRAYNAME[1]}
```

In the above code when i run my script as

```
$ sh ex1.sh
```

it gives an error message:

```
ex1.sh: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Why is this?

Comment: Run `bash ex1.sh` when you want to use `bash` features (not found in the POSIX shell).

Answer (score 5):

`sh` on your system is not bash.

Comment: Exactly.  The `#!/bin/bash` says to run the script using `/bin/bash`, but by running it with `sh ex1.sh`, you ignore that and run it using `sh`.  Just run it as `./ex1.sh`.  (And the `.sh` suffix isn't really needed.)

Answer (score 0):

Your "shebang" lines uses bash shell ("/bin/bash") but you're probably invoking another shell ("sh") invoking another shell to execute your script. Try this :

$ chmod 700 ex1.sh

This will make your script executable. Then run it :

$ ./ex1.sh